Access to cross gable attic
I recently have been doing electrical work to install ceiling fans in my house. However, in the front office, there is a cross gable roof.
When looking in the attic, I can get to just past the door frame, but then I hit decking of the main roof. I have access to the switch I will use, but not to the center of the room.
My thought is attaching romex to the end of a pull through drill bit.

Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to get the cable from the center of the room to your axcess point in the attic?  My question would be how do you intend to mount a proper fan rated box in the ceiling? Pulling the cable can be done easily with a hook on the end of a piece of 1/2" pvc pipe.

Also, some photos might help your case.  We can't see what you're seeing.

Welcome! The title and the body seem to ask different questions - the title seems to ask "how do I gain physical access to this separate partition of attic?" while the body asks "how do I fish cable blind into/through this separate attic?" We could help with either.
